# iOS app login through API not working (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a client application for the iOS which should access the server and post/get data from it.
I set up all the necesary methods for the URL request and receiving JSON, but for some reason it does not seam to work.
The application runs perfectly and when I click login nothing happens.
I am a beginner and and can not figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
   MY API host: api.sis.kemoke.net
   Login API route: POST    /auth/login | form params: email, password         return: json containing jwt token and user type
```

Login info
       email: cebic.ad@gmail.com
       password: Adin12345

My login screen class:

```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

let login_url = "https://sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
let checksession_url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net"

@IBOutlet var username_input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password_input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var login_button: UIButton!

var login_session:String = "/auth/login/"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    username_input.text = ""
    password_input.text = ""

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    if preferences.object(forKey: "session") != nil {
        login_session = preferences.object(forKey: "session") as! String
        check_session()
    }
    else {
        LoginToDo()
    }
}

@IBAction func DoLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if login_button.titleLabel?.text == "Logout" {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")
        LoginToDo()
    }
    else {
        login_now(username:username_input.text!, password: password_input.text!)
    }
}

func login_now(username:String, password:String) {
    let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    post_data.setValue(username, forKey: "email")
    post_data.setValue(password, forKey: "password")

    let url:URL = URL(string: login_url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    var paramString = ""

    for  (key, value) in post_data {
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }

    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {

        data, response, error in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            return
        }

        let json: Any?

        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            return
        }
        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }

        if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String {
                self.login_session = session_data

                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)

            }
        }
    }
    )

    task.resume()
}
func check_session() {
    let post_data: NSDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    post_data.setValue(login_session, forKey: "session")

    let url:URL = URL(string: checksession_url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    var paramString = ""

    for (key, value) in post_data {
        paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
    }

    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {

        data, response, error in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let json: Any?
        do {
            json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
        }
        catch {
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }

        if let response_code = server_response["response_code"] as? Int {
            if(response_code == 200) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
            }
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginToDo)
            }
        }
    }
    )
    task.resume()
}
func LoginDone() {
    username_input.isEnabled = false
    password_input.isEnabled = false
    login_button.isEnabled = true
    login_button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
    print("Login successful")
}

func LoginToDo() {
    username_input.isEnabled = true
    password_input.isEnabled = true

    login_button.isEnabled = true


    login_button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
}
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked your `login_now(username:password:)` is actually called by putting a breakpoint or inserting a debug output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing here may happens, because you *are not provide **body length** as required*. Although, putting data with POST method little harder than simple GET.

Solution for you - it's good to investigate in networking with Swift, but if you need just simply do it, so look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). Hope this may help you

EDIT: here is simple code:

```
    let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
    let parameters = ["email": "cebic.ad@gmail.com", "password": "Adin12345"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response) in

        print(response.result.value)

    }
```

And here we get response:

```
Optional({
jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjZWJpYy5hZEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0ODE0MTE0NDQsImlzcyI6ImtlbW9rZS5uZXQiLCJleHAiOjE0ODE0OTc4NDR9.3jFY0zRsvuJt3tq8dOzfJt8E6GxTisXZQRLHbugpeT4";
type = Admin;
})
```

I hope you can install library through pod system. Otherwise, at their github profile they have got instruction.

P.S. Don't forget mark question as resolved and like me :)

Comment: That username and password are just for testing purposes, no damage can be done :).

Comment: I understand :) Just mentioned for you to be carefully

Comment: Kislyu - could you please explain me how to do it this way as the Alamofire is getting me even more headache.

Comment: Ok, you want example?

Comment: Yes, just use my code and correct it or point where I am making a mistake. P.S. Edit the answer.

Comment: I did example for you. Happy coding!

Comment: Is it possible to use 2 parameters variables because I want that to be entered using textfields?

Comment: Of course. I just used predefined values. And close this question using checkmark